# Salesforce SSO through Amazon Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito as identity provider and Salesforce as service provider. I have done all the configuration in both cognito and salesforce and it is working as expected when using hosted UI. But I don't want to use hosted UI. Users should be able to redirect to salesforce after getting authenticated from cognito. How can I configure this without using cognito hosted UI?

I was also tracking network calls that is makes during the SSO. In one of the network call I found cognitoAsfData being sent in request body, I am not sure how cognito generates this data and did not find anyting in documentation as well.

Below is the curl request of the same network call -

```
  -H 'authority: auth.lumen-release.unext.tech' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=0cd7dd41-63fe-4337-9b65-XXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'origin: https://auth.lumen-release.unext.tech' \
  -H 'referer: https://auth.lumen-release.unext.tech/login?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/login&scope=email+openid+profile' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '_csrf=0cd7dd41-63fe-4337-9b65-XXXXXXXXXXXX&username=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXX&cognitoAsfData=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&signInSubmitButton=Sign+in' \
  --compressed
```

This request will return the code in the specified redirect URL that I will catch and get the token using the code.